# Unconstrained optimization problem (lasso with modification)

Tags: optimization

I am looking to solve the following unconstrained optimization problem:

$$\arg \min_U  \|b-A(UY^*)\|_F^2+\lambda\|U\|_1$$

where $\|.\|_F$ is frobenius norm.

I know that the solution without the $\lambda\|U\|_1$ term, will be the least square problem in the form of $AUY^* = b$. How can I solve this problem considering the sparsity constraint.

Comment: Does it help to write $\|U\|_1 = \max_j \sum_i |[U]_{ij}|$?

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868934/what-numerical-methods-are-known-to-solve-l-1-regularized-quadratic-programmin).