# How to solve a set of $L_1$ quadratic problems with a simple constraint efficiently?

Tags: convex-optimization

I have a set of problem each in the following form except with different $i$ in the constraint:

$$\min_x \tfrac{1}{2}x^T A x + b^Tx + \lambda ||x||_1$$
$$s.t. \quad x_i = a$$

where $x,b\in\mathbf{R}^n$, and $A\in \mathbf{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite, and $\lambda\in\mathbf{R}$ is positive?

How do you suggest to solve this set of problems?
It is essentially [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868934/what-numerical-methods-are-known-to-solve-l-1-regularized-quadratic-programmin) with just a constraint $x_i = a$.

Comment: Do not post [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658583/how-to-solve-this-set-of-l1-quadratic-problems-efficiently) twice (even with minor edits).

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't see that I submitted twice. What should I do?

Comment: Delete the other question!

Comment: It *is* the same as that problem. If you substitute $x_i=a$ into the objective, you can construct a reduced $\tilde{A}$ and $\tilde{b}$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, what about solving all of the problems efficiently? Can't we use the solution of a problem to obtain the solution of others?

Comment: I doubt there's an easy answer here. You might get some savings by using warm start from one solution to another.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelGrant