# soft thresholding derivation with two terms

Tags: derivatives, optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

I am trying to minimize the following function
$$argmin_x||x-y||^2_2 + ||x-z||_2^2 + \lambda || \frac{x- w}{c}||_1$$

I have been doing it for while but i am not sure how to do it. I have already been through few of the examples for simple cases such as this one ([Derivation of soft thresholding operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471339/derivation-of-soft-thresholding-operator)).

Taking the derivative w.r.t $x$ is given by

$$\frac{x{-w}}{\left|c\right|\left|x{-w}\right|}+4x{-2z}{-2y}$$,
i would like to know that how i would be able to go from here to the soft thresholding function described in the above link.

Any help regarding this would be quite useful

Comment: Why not just perform a variable substitution: $\tilde{x} = (x - w)/c$ so that your objective becomes $$\|c\tilde{x}+w-y\|_2^2+\|c\tilde{x}+w-z\|_2^2+\lambda\|\tilde{x}\|_1?$$

Comment: Do @MichaelGrant's variable substitution, and then complete the square in $c\tilde{x}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After applying @MichaelGrant 's variable substitution $u=(x-w)/c$ you end up with

$$ \arg \min_u \Vert cu+w-y\Vert^2 + \Vert cu+w-z\Vert^2 + \lambda \Vert u \Vert_1$$

which basically looks like the standard soft-thresholding 
$$\arg \min_u (1/2)\Vert u-p\Vert^2 + \lambda \Vert u\Vert_1 $$

after some manipulation of the two other terms i.e.

$$\Vert cu+w-y\Vert^2 + \Vert cu+w-z\Vert^2 = 2 c^2 \left\Vert u-\frac{2w-y-z}{c} \right\Vert^2 + f(w,y,z) $$

and it becomes

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\arg \min_u 2 c^2 \left\Vert u-\frac{2w-y-z}{c} \right\Vert^2 + \lambda \Vert u\Vert_1 & = &
4c^2 \arg \min_u \frac{1}{2}\left\Vert u-\frac{2w-y-z}{c} \right\Vert^2 + \frac{\lambda}{4c^2} \Vert u\Vert_1 \\ 
& = & 4c^2 S_{\lambda / 4c^2} \left( \frac{2w-y-z}{c} \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where $S_\rho$ is the soft-thresholding function with parameter $\rho$.