# Positive-semidefinite-constrained nuclear-norm-regularized optimization problem

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem:

Let $S \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ be a symmetric matrix, and fix $n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $n$ is significantly less than $p$ and the rank of $S$ is at most $n$. Now, I want to find a positive-semidefinite real matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ that minimizes

$\lVert S-R \rVert_{F} + \lambda \lVert R \rVert_{*},$

where $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{F}$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{*}$ are Frobenius norm and nuclear norm, respectively, and $\lambda > 0$ is a regularization parameter to be tuned via cross-validation. What is the best way to solve this optimization problem?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the solution in [The Proximal Operator of the Nuclear Norm / Schatten Norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009274).

It will give you a closed form solution for any $\lambda$.

Comment: How can I make sure the resulting matrix, the minimizer, is positive-(semi)definite? Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: @Eco-nometrician, Take only the non negative values.