# Algorithm (SciPy?) for Solving Optimization Problem with Absolute Values

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, python, non-convex-optimization

I am at a point in n-dimensional space $X^0$ and it costs me to move to $X_i$ with varying cost depending on direction $\Sigma_i c_i |X_i-X^0_i|$.

But, it's good for me to move closer to a target point $X^*$ because I'm penalized quadratically for being away from the target $d \Sigma_i |X_i-X^*_i|^2$.

I know the absolute values make this problematic but is there a way to globally minimize the total cost function for $X_i$? (algorithmically?)

$Cost =\Sigma_i c_i |X_i-X^0_i| + d \Sigma_i |X_i-X^*_i|^2$

Comment: It seems like you're asking an algorithms question - in which case you'd get better answers over at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) instead.

Comment: Sure I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The cost function I see is plainly sum of functions each depending on a single (and unique) coordinate. If that is it, it may perfectly well be optimized coordinate-wise. And, by the way, why this is tagged 'non-convex optimization'? ;)

Comment: @rhaskett: You might also want to take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471339/derivation-of-soft-thresholding-operator).

Comment: @metamorphy I think I see. If I shift the problem to where it is along a line between X^0 and X^* it becomes a 1D quadratic problem and I can split the space where X>X^0 and X<X^0 to deal with the absolute value.

Comment: Minimizing absolute value is expressible as a linear problem: $x\geq |y|$ is the same as $x\geq y \geq -x$. The square can be handled with a second-order cone.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek only if $c_i \geq 0$.

Comment: Yes, it is a cost so $c_i \geq 0$.

Comment: Do you have a link where I can learn about that transformation?