# regression optimisation problem with $l_1$ and $l_2$ norms for $x \in \Bbb R^n$

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem: 
$$\text{argmin}_{x \in \Bbb R^n}~ f(x),~ f(x) = ||x - a||_2 ^2 + \lambda ||x||_1,~ \lambda>0.$$

Any thoughts on how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is this any different from the case you know of by simply identifying $A=I$ and $b = -a$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!

Comment: This looks to be a convex optimization problem, since the L1 and L2 norms are both convex functions over the domain supplied, and $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: Looks like Lagrangian form of *Lasso*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a soft-thresholding problem for linear regression, for which a closed-form solution is provided here: [Derivation of Soft Thresholding Operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471339/derivation-of-soft-thresholding-operator)